# A partition of primes based on the sum of the digits

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Given a prime number $p$
$$p=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i10^i$$
consider the function
$$ds(p)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i$$
For example: $\;ds(3)=3,\;ds(11)=2,\;ds(97)=16,\;ds(103)=4$.

Let's define the family of sets
$$S_m=\{p\;\,prime:ds(p)=m\}$$
$$|S_1|=0\;\;\;|S_2|=3?\;\;\;|S_3|=1\;\;\;|S_6|=0\;\;\;|S_9|=0\;\;\;|S_{3k}|=0\;(k\gt1)$$
**For which values of $m$, $|S_m|$ is finite?**

Comment: What did you try? Show your attempts in accordance with [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Given any $m$, there are only a finite number of natural numbers whose sum of digits is $m$. So, there must be only a finite number of primes. So, the answer to your question is that for all values of $m$, $|S_m|$ is finite.

Comment: @SayanDutta : Your comment is false, due to the existence of the number 0.

Comment: @SayanDutta That's not correct. Take a number that starts and ends with 1, and has infinitely many zeroes in between. There are infinitely many of these, and the sum of their digits is always 2.

Comment: @Sambo How can you have infinitely many zeroes in between?

Comment: @Sambo yes, right!

Comment: Oops, that's a typo; I meant arbitrarily many zeroes.

Comment: The observation $|S_{3k}|=0$ for $k>1$ is good.  For the conjecture about $|S_2|$, one needs to evaluate numbers of the form $10^k+1$ (are 11 and 101 the only ones?)  I observe that $10^{2n+1}+1$ is divisible by 11 for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: @Michael this seems to be an open problem, related to whether there are infinitely many Fermat primes.

Comment: We know a prime can only have a sum of digits congruent to itself mod 3 ...

Comment: One simple observation the other way: there are infinitely many $n$ for which $S_n$ is non-empty. (This can be shown using Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions)

Answer (score 2):

To confirm something stated in the comments, it is an open problem to determine whether or not $S_2$ is finite. $S_2$ consists of primes of the form $10^n+1$, which must further be of the form $10^{2^k}+1$. [This page](http://www.prothsearch.com/GFN10.html) summarizes the current state of the art for for factoring numbers of the form $F_m(10)=10^{2^m}+1$. They have verified $F_m(10)$ is composite for all $m\le 30$ except $m=0,1$, but the question is open for all but finitely many $m$.